# How can I make jshint indent options work

Tags: javascript, node.js, jshint

jslint can check indent by run 'jslint --indent 4 test.js', but I don't get it work in jshint.
I do it as the follow steps.

1. install jshint through "npm install -g jshint"
2. edit ~/.jshintrc, my jshintrc looks like

   ```
   {..., "indent":4, "white":false, ...}
   ```
3. edit js file test.js

   ```
   /jshint indent:4/
   var condition, doSth;
   if (condition)
   doSth(); // expected to be invalid
   ```
4. run jshint test.js, but the indent checking is not working. The 2 spaces started line can pass the check.

Answer (score 15):

It's a version problem. I use 2.5.0 while 2.4 works.

Take a look at https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases/tag/2.5.0:

> We decided to label it 2.5.0 because—while it's backwards
>   compatible—there are a few major changes.
>
> The following options were removed: nomen, onevar, passfail, white,
>   gcl, smarttabs, trailing. In addition to that, indent no longer
>   provides warnings about indentation levels. You can still use it to
>   set your tab-width but it will be used only for character locations in
>   other warnings. JSHint won't error if you have these options in your
>   config or your files; it will simply ignore them.
>
> Thanks to our contributors, we fixed a lot of bugs in our parser. We
>   also improved our ES6 support by adding basic support for template
>   literals.

Comment: Does anyone happen to know the justification for removing those options? They were very useful for keeping styles in check.

Comment: @dave see [JSHint issue #1358](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1358#issuecomment-39587645) and [JSHint 3 plans](http://www.jshint.com/blog/jshint-3-plans/). In short, the creator of JSHint, Anton Kovalyov, plans to focus on other aspects of code analysis and feels that style checking should be part of another tool/add-on. I understand the need to have a succinct focus. Now my question is just what will that tool be. Some comments in the JSHint issue suggest [JSCS](https://github.com/mdevils/node-jscs). I plan to start there.