# Grunt JSHint - Not checking indentations

Tags: gruntjs, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

I have the `indent` set to 4. If I remove all the indentations in a source file, JSHint doesn't fail for it. It checks everything else but the indentations. How do I get it to check for indentations?

Additionally, I have installed the [jshint-eclipse](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/install.html) plugin, it too doesn't work!

Here is the excerpt of my GruntFile:

```
// Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
jshint: {
  options: {
    jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
    reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
  },
  all: {
    src: [
      'Gruntfile.js',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
    ]
  },
  test: {
    options: {
      jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
    },
    src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
  }
},
```

And my jshint:

```
{
  "node": true,
  "browser": true,
  "esnext": true,
  "bitwise": true,
  "camelcase": true,
  "curly": true,
  "eqeqeq": true,
  "immed": true,
  "indent": 4,
  "latedef": true,
  "newcap": true,
  "noarg": true,
  "quotmark": "single",
  "regexp": true,
  "undef": true,
  "unused": true,
  "strict": true,
  "trailing": true,
  "smarttabs": false,
  "globals": {
      "angular": false
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Gruntfile (or as little of it as you need to reproduce the problem) so we can help troubleshoot?

Comment: Yes... Let me update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: `npm install grunt-contrib-jshint@0.9.2`

---

Turns out this is a dupe of [How can I make jshint indent options work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097316/how-can-i-make-jshint-indent-options-work).

No accepted answer, but [the only answer present](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23098280/803749) suggests it's an issue with the version of JSHint that's installed. 2.5.0 dropped support for the `indent` option and some other style things.

When I just installed `grunt-contrib-jshint` normally, I got version 0.10.0 and had the same problem as OP (because 0.10.0 depends on JSHint 2.5.0); when I instead installed `grunt-contrib-jshint@0.9.2` (the last release that used JSHint 2.4.0 instead), my results lit up with a bunch of indentation errors (as expected).

Comment: Yes, true that. I was pointed to the same post by my colleague! Unfortunately we have to rely on our editor to take care of the indentations and tabs/spaces issue. Thanks for the help mate!